# How does "make" app know default target to build if no target is specified?

Tags: makefile

Most Linux apps are compiled with:

```
make
make install clean
```

As I understand it, the `make` command takes names of build targets as arguments. So for example `install` is usually a target that copies some files to standard locations, and `clean` is a target that removes temporary files.

But what target will `make` build if no arguments are specified (e.g. the first command in my example)?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

By default, it begins by processing the first target that does not begin with a `.` aka [the default goal](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html); to do that, it may have to process other targets - specifically, ones the first target depends on.

The [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) covers all this stuff, and is a surprisingly easy and informative read.

Comment: Not the target "all" as previous answer states? :(

Comment: Calling the first target `all` is just a convention.

Comment: And if i issue "make install" it will only build "install" target. skipping first one is "install" don't depend on it, correct?

Comment: Correct, but 'install' almost certainly DOES depend on it - 'install' is typically the most dependent rule, because it needs all the exes, libraries etc. Of course, you can also write an 'install' rule that just does a copy.

Comment: Historically, the advice has always been to do 'make && make install' rather than relying on the dependencies of the install target.  Many projects will not build correctly (or at all) if you try to just do 'make install'.

Comment: It's useful to run them separately if you're installing for other users, as you then only need to run the `make install` in sudo, rather than the entire build.

Comment: FYI the default man entry for make makes no mention of what happens when you don't specify a target..

Comment: If the GNU make manual covers this stuff, why was this question asked?  The manual is great at documenting how to write rules, but makes no mention on how to write a Makefile.

Comment: @anon What if the makefile include a .mk file before its first target? will it execute the first target of .mk file or its own first target?

Comment: I'm looking at a make file that `include`s another makefile, whose first target is `%.o : %.cpp`. So the default target is... to build all .cpp files?

Answer (score 309):

To save others a few seconds, and to save them from having to read the manual, here's the short answer. Add this to the top of your make file:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := mytarget
```

mytarget will now be the target that is run if "make" is executed and no target is specified.

If you have an older version of make (<= 3.80), this won't work. If this is the case, then you can do what anon mentions, simply add this to the top of your make file:

```
.PHONY: default
default: mytarget ;
```

References:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html

Comment: @nathan It makes mytarget the default target if someone runs "make" without any parameters.

Comment: Note that .DEFAULT_GOAL doesn't appear to be supported in GNU make v3.80, and I would assume prior versions as well (v3.81 does support it though). If you are running an older version of make you will have to make sure your default target is the first/topmost target in your make file.

Comment: is `default:` a special target name, or this works because it's the first target in the file?

Comment: I know Samuel says it but it does indeed appear that .PHONY and default: mytarget should be before mytarget at the least (or at top of file as mentioned)

Comment: "...to save them from having to read the manual" is one of the points of SO: quick answers to questions that would otherwise take awhile to dig for in ancient documentation.

Comment: "Add this to the top of your make file": Adding to the top does not seem to be a requirement.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Explicit over implicit wins in this case.

Answer (score 47):

GNU Make also allows you to specify the default make target using a special variable called `.DEFAULT_GOAL`. You can even unset this variable in the middle of the Makefile, causing the next target in the file to become the default target.

Ref: [The Gnu Make manual - Special Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables)

Answer (score 1):

bmake's equivalent of GNU Make's `.DEFAULT_GOAL` is `.MAIN`:

```
$ cat Makefile
.MAIN: foo

all:
    @echo all

foo:
    @echo foo
$ bmake
foo
```

See the [bmake(1) manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports).