# mingw32-make only runs the first dependency line

Tags: makefile, mingw, mingw-w64

My Makefile:

```
helloworldlib.obj: helloworldlib.cpp
    g++ -Wall -o helloworldlib.obj -c helloworldlib.cpp

helloworld.obj: source.cpp
    g++ -Wall -o helloworld.obj -c source.cpp

helloworld.exe: source.cpp helloworld.obj
    g++ -Wall -o helloworld.exe helloworld.obj helloworldlib.obj
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with this, when I run mingw32-make it only executes the first `g++ -Wall -o helloworldlib.obj -c helloworldlib.cpp`.
As far as I know this makefile is syntactically correct, mingw just doesn't seem to be able to find the other lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `make` works. If no target is provided on the command line (e.g. `mingw32-make helloworld.exe`), by default it builds the first target defined in the file. See for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057716/2249356.

As a quick fix, you can just move the rule for `helloworld.exe` to the top of the file and then `make` will build all.

And, I think that the last rule is supposed to read

```
helloworld.exe: helloworld.obj helloworldlib.obj
    g++ -Wall -o helloworld.exe helloworld.obj helloworldlib.obj
```

rather then with the `source.cpp` and its object code `helloworld.obj` as dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. As an aside, do you know why using `ming32-make` with the `-B` (make all targets) switch doesn't work, if it actually does read the other lines?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I have never used `-B`. The documentation is quite brief, it might have some restrictions.

Comment: The documentation for [-B](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) says: `Consider all targets out-of-date`. Which means it will always rebuild all dependencies even if no sources changed. But you still have to choose the actual target, or it uses the first one in the makefile as before.